# How to set Home country for Google Now?

Tags: geolocation, 4.1-jelly-bean, google-now

I'm living in UK and all my apps understand it. All except Google Now. It keeps showing me cards about the rate between $ and £ or time in US (supposed to be time at home).

I checked all my settings and UK is set every where even for my Google account. I've got a Nexus S running Jelly Bean that I bought in UK.

How to make Google now understand that I live in UK? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you set a home address in latitude?

Comment: Works! Thank you! Set it as an answer and I'll give you reward!

Comment: To direct a message to a specific user, use '@' before the user's name. @RichardBorcsik will ensure that this gets to its inbox. :) **ps:** *this message should already have alerted Richard to come here.*

Comment: Thanks @Zuul but I already got notified :) I only recently noticied the actual pattern of how notifications work. If you're the only commenter and the owner of the question adds a comment after you, you're notified. But this is a special case.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Nice, didn't know about that detail, tks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Now by default will think that you're in the USA.
The app pulls your home address from Google Latitude. This is also how it knows when you're home and it is the basics for traffic info.

To change this go into:

```
Maps ->  Location History (tab)
```

Here you can set both your home and work address.